# Algebraic Topology problem help! A mapping from the n-sphere to some set!

Tags: algebraic-topology

So let $f:S^{m}\to X$ be a continuous mapping. How can I prove that a) $f$ is homotopic with the constant mapping (i.e. the point I guess) and b) that $f$ can be augmented to a new mapping $f': D^{m+1}\to X$ (i.e. from the unit disk in $m+1$ dimensions to $X$) are equivalent?

Comment: In general $f$ will not be homotopic to a constant map. Do you have more information about $f$? Also, what is $Y$? Related to $X$ in any way?

Comment: Sorry I made a typo $Y=X$. As for $f$ I know nothing more. I  just think that I have to show that the sentences a) and b) are equivalent. Not to show that each one it true by itself. Does this make it easier?

Comment: You should edit your question in that case

Answer (score 2):

A hint to get you going: Let $H:S^m \times I \to X$ be a homotopy from $f$ to a constant map. Then $H$ is constant when restricted to $S^m \times \{1\}$, so it factors through the quotient space $S^m\times I / S^m \times \{1\}$ (i.e. it induces a map from this space to $X$). But that quotient space is exactly $D^{m+1}$! Can you see why?

Comment: Hmm no. I think I am more confused actually :/ Can you elaborate it a bit more please?

Comment: The quotient space I described is what is called [the "cone" on a space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone_%28topology%29). Try to imagine the cone on $S^1$, and convince yourself that it is the same as $D^2$. Generally, the cone on $S^m$ is homeomorphic to $D^{m+1}$

Comment: Ok I am confused. You show that $f$ is homotopic with a constant map because you define a homotopy that is restricted to $S^m \times \{1\}$ which is the srinking of a circle to a point, right?

Comment: But the cone of $X$ which is $CX$ is the product space $X \times [0,1]/equivalency class$. Why have you put it to be $X \times \{1\}$?

Comment: That notation means that we identify all points in $X\times\{1\}$ with each other, and make no other identifications.

Comment: Ok, I think I got why the two sentences are equivalent. I just need to make sure I understand the cone thing better. Thanks!